# To much fillColor in google maps api polygon

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have following issue with drawing a polygon with google maps api. It looks like that there is to much fillColor. The center of the following polygon is not supposed to have fillColor.

Is it google maps API or is it me who has a bug?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/zCA2u/

[image]

```
$(function(){
var shape;

var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(24.886436490787712, -70.2685546875),
    zoom: 4,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var coords = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(31.50362, -70.0488),
    new google.maps.LatLng(29.91685, -62.4023),
    new google.maps.LatLng(22.91792, -56.42578),
    new google.maps.LatLng(22.67484, -69.6972),
    new google.maps.LatLng(27.29368, -74.8828),
    new google.maps.LatLng(33.06392, -73.3007),
    new google.maps.LatLng(34.23451, -66.0058),
    new google.maps.LatLng(32.32427, -58.2714),
    new google.maps.LatLng(26.35249, -56.4257),
    new google.maps.LatLng(18.81271, -60.64453),
    new google.maps.LatLng(20.13847, -69.4335)
];

shape = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: coords,
    strokeColor: '#ff0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    draggable: true,
    fillColor: '#ff0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
});

shape.setMap(map);
```

});

I have now tried the above in IE8 and it renders correct in IE8
[image]

Comment: As far as I can tell there is no bug? The exterior bounds of the polygon form a complete shape and so the entire interior of the outermost is filled. If the edges didn't touch then the area you point at with the arrow should be clear but they do.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6171

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make "holes" in polygons

1. they aren't supported by the drawing manager directly
2. you need to have separate paths (the polygon "paths" property takes an array)
3. the inner paths (the "holes") need to wind in the opposite direction from the inner path

[simple example of a polygon with a hole (a donut)](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_polygon_example_donut.html)

[fiddle with self intersection removed and hole](http://jsfiddle.net/qdVLt/1/)

```
var coords = [
 [  new google.maps.LatLng(27.29368, -74.8828),
    new google.maps.LatLng(33.06392, -73.3007),
    new google.maps.LatLng(34.23451, -66.0058),
    new google.maps.LatLng(32.32427, -58.2714),
    new google.maps.LatLng(26.35249, -56.4257),
    new google.maps.LatLng(18.81271, -60.64453),
    new google.maps.LatLng(20.13847, -69.4335)
],
    [
    new google.maps.LatLng(21.534847,-63.28125),
    new google.maps.LatLng(30.221102,-59.677734), 
    new google.maps.LatLng(30.600094,-71.279297)
    ]
];
```

Comment: The purpose is not to make holes. I just think that there is a difference between where I can drag the polygon and where the fillColor is. I believe that there should not be fillColor in the center.

Comment: Self-intersecting polygons are a difficult problem (they aren't really supported).  If you expect there not to be fill in the intersection, it needs to be a separate path and wind the opposite direction.  Calculating that from the points you have is possible, but not trivial.